# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable WebDriver object using Chrome browser Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, flask, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a Flask web application with Selenium Webdriver using Chrome Browser that open Google Maps and search a location based on input by user. Error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable WebDriver object" appeared after the location name has been input to my web and the Google Maps search box.

It said the error occured in the bow.open_chrome() function. But that function only for opening Chrome WebDriver window.

Here's the app.py (routing) code :

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['POST','GET'])
def testing():
        if request.method == "POST":
            nama_rm = request.form['nama_resto']
            print(nama_rm)
            aspek = ['makanan', 'minuman', 'pelayanan', 'tempat', 'harga']
            model_final = {}
            vectorizer_final = {}
            

            open_chrome, driver = bow.open_chrome()

            search_resto = bow.search_resto(nama_rm, driver)

            redirect_page = bow.redirect_reviewstab(driver)

            scroll_page = bow.scroll_reviewstab(driver)

            iterate_allreviews,  = bow.iteration_allreviews(driver)

            preprocess_input = bow.proses_df_input(df, vectorizer_final, model_final, aspek)

            return jsonify({'df':df})
```

Here's the model code :

```
def open_chrome():
    #London Victoria & Albert Museum URL
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    url = 'https://www.google.co.id/maps/@3.5508653,98.6270636,15z'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    
    return driver
    
def search_resto(nama_resto, driver):
    # find the search bar element
    search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]')

    # input the place name or address
    search_bar.send_keys(nama_resto)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Here's the error messages :
 `File "e:\Folder Kuliah\Skripsi\Apps\webflask\Aplikasi\app.py", line 41, in testing open_chrome, driver = bow.open_chrome() TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable WebDriver object`

I wonder where's the source of the problem. I really apreciate any response and help from you, Thank You!

Comment: Is `open_chrome, driver =` a typo? Your `open_chrome` method returns a single driver object, not a tuple or list.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thank you for reminding me. I've tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you so much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The error complains about this line, not the `open_chrome()` method :

```
open_chrome, driver = bow.open_chrome()
```

The method returns a single object, not a tuple. I suspect this is a typo and what you intended to write is

```
driver = bow.open_chrome()
```